# Is there a way to add a column to a specific position in Interbase

Tags: position, alter, interbase

I need to add a new column to an existing table in my database.

The column should be placed in a specific position.

I know this can be done in two separate commands:

```
ALTER TABLE MYTABLE
ADD MYCOL INTEGER


ALTER TABLE MYTABLE
ALTER MYCOL POSITION 12
```

But is there a way to do this in just one?

I searched Interbase's documentation and found nothing that refers to this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE MYTABLE
ADD MYCOL INTEGER,
ALTER COLUMN MYCOL POSITION 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes; you can chain one or more operations to the ALTER TABLE syntax.
See http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/InterBase/2020/en/ALTER_TABLE

Batsheva's answer above is correct.